# java: check if WGS84 point is within a polygon if not get the distance

Tags: java, wgs84

as mentioned in the title I'm searching for a possibillity to check if a given point in wgs84-format is within an given polygon and if not I want to find the shortest distance from that point to the polgon. Maybe there exists any library.

Thank you for the help

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Java Topology Suite. This has a point in polygon function, and distance functions, among many others. To check if a point is inside a polygon it doesn't really matter what the coordinate system is.

http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTS_Topology_Suite

If you want to convert from one coordinate system to another, have a look at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTS_Topology_Suite

Both of these libraries (JTS in the guise of the C++ port, GEOS) form part of the very popular Postgis extension to Postgres, if you ever want to move you spatial analysis to a database.

Comment: java.awt.Polygon also has a point in polygon function, though this won't help you with the distance function: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#contains(java.awt.geom.Point2D)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use GeoTools (http://www.geotools.org/). They are an excellent open-source Java library for geospatial data.